# I cannot run the gallery app code from the book Spring Persistence with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

I downloaded this code from this address: http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/528/

This is the code used in the book Spring Persistence with Hibernate

And then I did some modifications so that it did not give any compile time errors. I just modified the pom.xml and others that relates with the oracle BD I´m using. I also changed all "comment" words to "comentario" becouse "comment" seems to be a reserved word in oracle and that was producing a error.

The resulting project can be downloaded from here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9578179/gallery.zip

I runned all the Junits tests in the project and all passed.

But when I try to run the main from the eclipse and selecting Tomcat 6.0.35 Server at local host the program doesn´t work.

When I try to access the page localhost:8080/gallery/home.jsp the following message appears:

```
HTTP Status 404 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message 

description The requested resource () is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

Can someone help me please?

The console show the following messages:

```
20/01/2012 13:48:11 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;.
20/01/2012 13:48:11 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVISO: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:gallery' did not find a matching property.
20/01/2012 13:48:11 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
20/01/2012 13:48:11 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 556 ms
20/01/2012 13:48:11 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
20/01/2012 13:48:11 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
20/01/2012 13:48:12 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[gallery]        0 [2012-01-20 13:48:14,702] [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/cesar.souza/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.1.RELEASE/GalleryFolder01/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/gallery/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/cesar.souza/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.1.RELEASE/GalleryFolder01/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/gallery/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: galleryPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/cesar.souza/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.1.RELEASE/GalleryFolder01/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/gallery/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: galleryPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:266)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: galleryPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:892)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not init listeners
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getInitializedEventListeners(Configuration.java:1396)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:883)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to initialize directory provider: com.prospringhibernate.gallery.domain.Category
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProviders(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.SearchFactoryImpl.initDocumentBuilders(SearchFactoryImpl.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.SearchFactoryImpl.<init>(SearchFactoryImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener.initialize(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners$1.processListener(EventListeners.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.processListeners(EventListeners.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:194)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to create index directory: C:\Program Files\springsource\sts-2.8.1.RELEASE\.\lucene\indexes for index com.prospringhibernate.gallery.domain.Category
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderHelper.getVerifiedIndexDir(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:129)
    ... 56 more
20/01/2012 13:48:14 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/cesar.souza/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.1.RELEASE/GalleryFolder01/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/gallery/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/cesar.souza/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.1.RELEASE/GalleryFolder01/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/gallery/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: galleryPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/cesar.souza/Documents/workspace-sts-2.8.1.RELEASE/GalleryFolder01/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/gallery/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: galleryPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:266)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: galleryPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:892)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not init listeners
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getInitializedEventListeners(Configuration.java:1396)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:883)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to initialize directory provider: com.prospringhibernate.gallery.domain.Category
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProviders(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.SearchFactoryImpl.initDocumentBuilders(SearchFactoryImpl.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.SearchFactoryImpl.<init>(SearchFactoryImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener.initialize(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners$1.processListener(EventListeners.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.processListeners(EventListeners.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:194)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to create index directory: C:\Program Files\springsource\sts-2.8.1.RELEASE\.\lucene\indexes for index com.prospringhibernate.gallery.domain.Category
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderHelper.getVerifiedIndexDir(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:129)
    ... 56 more
20/01/2012 13:48:14 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
20/01/2012 13:48:14 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Context [/gallery] startup failed due to previous errors
20/01/2012 13:48:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
20/01/2012 13:48:14 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
20/01/2012 13:48:15 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
20/01/2012 13:48:15 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/32  config=null
20/01/2012 13:48:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3335 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

from the log:

Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to create index directory: `C:\Program Files\springsource\sts-2.8.1.RELEASE\.\lucene\indexes` for index com.prospringhibernate.gallery.domain.Category

You have a problem with a certain path: does it exist?
Where does it come from (e.g. which properties file)?

Comment: I changed hibernate.search.default.indexBase to the full path: C:\\Users\\cesar.souza\\Documents\\workspace-sts-2.8.1.RELEASE\\GalleryFolder01\\gallery\\lucene\\indexes. But the same error message appears. I also have already cleaned the project

Comment: Very cool! But I think the error message is hardly the same -- or the changing of the `hibernate.search.default.indexBase` property have not gotten into effect. so here's what I suggest: update your post. Add this information about setting the path and replace the error message with the new one.

Comment: I resolved the problem. It had to do with admin permissions which I don´t have. So I moved my eclipse folder to a folder where I have permissions and it worked. But I still can´t access all pages in the webapp. But no error appears in the console. I think this error will be difficult to find since the console don´t show any error message. Thanks for your help.